# install geary mail xubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, xubuntu, geary

I have trouble getting geary to run on my laptop. It does not want to start. I run Xubuntu 14.04.

I tried installing it from command line, software centre and synaptics, but it does not start.

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your post, to clarify how you actually installed it?

Comment: i succeed to install geary, BUT i can't select any mailbox, no reaction, it only display the first account added inbox and nothing else i can select.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have attempted to run Geary before, since it reports your database is at version 21. You could try backing up `~/.local/share/geary`, then deleting it, and running Geary again and seeing if that makes any difference.

Note however version 0.6 that you have installed is *very* old — the latest version is 0.12. If you add the [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/~geary-team/+archive/ubuntu/releases) to your system then Geary will be upgraded to 0.11, which may well work much better.